# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" when trying to compare string

Tags: python, if-statement, discord.py, typeerror

Im currently writing a game for a bot in discord.py, which has a leaderboard.
for the leaderboard i am using a nested list with a lenght of 100 (max players),
which contains a name and a score ("name", "score") in every index.
Whenever i try to use my for loop to check exceptions, the console throws
this at me: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

```
for i in leaderboard:
    if benutzerstr[x]==leaderboard[i][0]:
      leaderboard[i][1]+=2
    else: 
      if leaderboard[i][0]!="name":
        i+=1
      else:
        leaderboard[i][0]=benutzerstr[x]
        leaderboard[i][1]=2
    i+=1
```

in my current case, benutzerstr[x] holds the name "darkcat." in it,
x has the value 3.
It would be nice to get a quick respond, as this problem is pretty
much holding me from making any progress with my bot.

Comment: what line raises the error ?

Comment: If `leaderboard` is a list, then `for i in leaderboard:` will pull out each element of the list and not the index. So you can use `i[0]` directly. If you need the index, then you need to do something like `for i in range(0, len(leaderboard)):` or `for idx, val in enumerate(leaderboard):`

Comment: @azro `if benutzerstr[x]==leaderboard[i][0]:`

Comment: do `print(x, i)` before the first if, and show us

Comment: @azro `0 ['name', 'score']` is returned, i think the tip than @Benjin gave me will fix this, i will try it.

Comment: It helped me, but it is stil not working as i want, because it puts the same name in every index of the list: 
 `1. ['darkcat.', 200]
  2. ['darkcat.', 200]
  3. ['darkcat.', 200]`

Comment: return the type of the val that you will print to see what is currently returned

Answer (score 1):

This here is my answer, i thought that `for i in leaderboard` was an index, but it wasn't. Thank you for your help.

```
for i in range(0, len(leaderboard)):
        if benutzerstr[x] not in leaderboard:
          if benutzerstr[x]==leaderboard[i][0]:
            leaderboard[i][1]+=2
          else: 
            if leaderboard[i][0]!="-":
                i+=1
            else:
              leaderboard[i][0]=benutzerstr[x]
              leaderboard[i][1]=2
```